# How exactly to process data on Hadoop,Hive,Pig

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, apache-pig, hadoop-partitioning

I have learnt the basics of Apache Hadoop Hive. And know majority of commands. Now, how to exactly work on the data. I have huge amt of data available with me(got it from a person). But dont know what exactly to do.

The data(.xlsx) is weekly sales, quarterly sales of a huge company (cant name it). The data is column wise sales of different products in different branches of US.

What processing can be done on this?
Should I filter the data before doing that?

Comment: People usually know what is to be done and search for tools and techniques to do the same. Here its reverse.

Comment: Haha ;-) :-). Actly I am new to this tool.. Learnt the basic commands using small set of data. Now i want to apply it for bigger set. Can u pls tell atleast what normally is done. Any hint will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try to find some interesting insights in the data like**:
1)  Largest selling products
2)  Products that are often bought together
3)  Branches with highest sale
4)  Optimum inventory levels: 
a.  When inventory drops to Zero – potential sales are lost
b.  Unused inventory, with no sales
5)  Time of the year when certain products are more in demand

Sounds intresting? This is just the starting

Comment: http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/how-to-process-data-with-apache-hive/                                                                   http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/how-to-process-data-with-apache-pig/

Comment: That sounds really interesting. I will deftly try one by one.. Thanks a lot kedar. 
I will surely contact you back..